# How to subset a data frame by pairing its columns

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I need to extract columns in such a way where I am selecting one and then the next one which is 288 columns away. For example:

```
 datanew <- data[, c(8, 296, 9, 297, 10, 298, 11, 299, 12, 300 etc)]
```

I need to do this up until 288, 576.

Could anybody suggest whether there is a quicker way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like

```
first_columns <- 8:288
next_columns <- first_columns+288
comb <- c(rbind(first_columns, next_columns))
```

This is the tricky part - since R stores matrices in column-first order, making a two-row matrix and then using `c()` to collapse it to a vector will make an interleaved vector of column numbers. (Checking with `head(comb)` shows `8 296 9 297 10 298 ...` as requested.)

Then do `data[, comb]`.

Another, somewhat more explicit way to do this:

```
comb <- rep(NA_real_, 2*(288-7))     ## set up vector (could also use numeric())
odds <- seq(1,length(comb), by=2)
evens <- seq(2, length(comb), by=2)
comb[odds] <- 8:288
comb[evens] <- comb[odds] + 288
```

Answer (score 3):

You can take advantage of recycling and do something like this:

```
datanew <- data[, rep(8:288, each=2) + c(0, 288)]
```